# Wiki like on http://wiki.asp.net (with hierarchical table of contents)

Tags: asp.net, wiki

I am looking for a **Wiki** written on **ASP.NET** (preferably **open source and free**) similar to the one on http://wiki.asp.net/.

The main feature that I like on http://wiki.asp.net/ is a **hierarchical table of contents** - something which is totally absent in most Wikis - which are just collections of pages connected via hyperlinks, with no place where you can see the "sitemap" of the Wiki. What I need is a more structured Wiki, with pages organized like in a file system.

Does anyone know such Wiki?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try ScrewTurn wiki it is very good and open source
http://www.screwturn.eu/MainPage.ashx

Comment: The problem with this Wiki is that they do not have a table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Deki wiki:

developer.mindtouch.com/Deki

You can see the auto generated table of contents on the left hand side. There is also a link to a full page table of contents.

Open source and very feature rich, I've used it on a few projects. There is a paid version as well, but I've never tried it.

Comment: Yeah, the table of contents looks right - but the thing that I did not like is that the table of contents makes postbacks to the server each time I try to open a node! So it works really slow. Aren't they going to create an AJAX table of contents, or, even easier, just fully populate the table of contents so that no postbacks would occur?